# Почему не работает *x++ в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, указатели

Изучая Objective-C, столкнулся с такой особенностью:
конструкция `*x++` работает непонятно, в то время как `*x += 1` работает так, как и ожидается, то есть увеличивает значение. В чем дело? Почему `*x++` работает неадекватно? Каких еще сюрпризов ждать от указателей?

```
int i = 17;
int *x = &i;
printf("i = %d\n", i);
*x++;    //Выдает 1606416696    Предупреждение:"Expression result unused"
//*x += 1; //Выдает 18
printf("*x = %d\n", *x);
```

PS: Я новичек в программировании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что

```
*x++;
```

понимается как

```
*(х++);
```

Результат разыменования игнорируется.

Возможно, вы хотите

```
(*х)++;
```

?

Comment: Спасибо (*х)++; работает.